# How do I replace a local file with the version in the SVN repository?

Tags: windows, svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

Using the TortoiseSVN right-click contextual menu, how do I replace a specific local file with the version currently on the SVN repository?

Comment: Yes, currently using TortoiseSVN, have edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is modified you can do `Revert` ( and follow it up with `Update` ). You can also choose `Update To Revision` and specify `HEAD revision` or choose the specific revision you want. Or you can just do `Update` to update to the latest version.